# wordpress to import joomla articles

Tags: wordpress, joomla1.5

I am using wordpress plugin `Joomla 1.5 Importer`  to import articles from joomla.
My joomla version is 1.5,  but when i tried to import i get this error

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.ashramyoga.com' (110) in /home/aaa/public_html/aaa/aaa/wp-content/plugins/joomla-15-importer/joomla-15-importer.php on line 177
```

Database connection failure: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.aaa.com' (110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than likely that your host is blocking access to it from external sources. Have you the correct hostname, for the mysql database?

Contact your host regarding external access to your MySQL database and get the correct host info for connecting to it.